# Bessel functions in resolution of second order ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, bessel-functions

We have the following equation:
$$
v''(r)+\frac{1}{r} v'(r) - w v(r)=0, \quad 0 < r < ε; \\ v'(0)=0,
$$
where $w$ is an positive constant.

To resolve this problem, we introduce a new independent variable $\xi= \sqrt{w} r$ and a new function $z(\xi)= v(r)$. Then 
$$
v'(r)=\sqrt{w} z'(\xi), \quad v''(r)= w z''(\xi),\\
z''(\xi)+\dfrac{1}{\xi} z'(\xi)- z(\xi)=0, \quad 0 < \xi < ε \sqrt{w},\\
z'(0)=0.
$$
Let $\zeta= i \xi (i=\sqrt{-1})$. Then 
$$
y''(\zeta)+ \dfrac{1}{\zeta} y'(\zeta)+ y(\zeta)=0, \quad 0 < |\zeta| < ε \sqrt{w}.
$$
We have 
$$
y(\zeta)= C J_0(\zeta),
$$
where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the zero order. We will use the asymptotic expansion 
$$
J_0(\zeta)=1- \dfrac{\zeta^2}{2^2}+ \frac{\zeta^4}{2^2 \cdot 4^2}- \cdots
$$
Solution of the problem writes 
$$
z(\zeta)= y(\zeta)= C J_0(i \xi)= C \left(1+\frac{\xi^2}{2^2}+ \dfrac{\xi^4}{2^2 \cdot 4^2}+\cdots \right).
$$

My questions are: i don't understand the method used to resolve this problem and why and how we introduce the Bessel functions?

Comment: In the first equation involving $\zeta$, you multiply both sides by $\zeta^2$ and now you have the Bessel ODE of order $0$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). By definition the solutions to this ODE are called Bessel functions of order zero, and we usually write them in terms of the basic Bessel functions $J_0$ and $Y_0$. I believe you have that $Y_0'(0)$ is infinite, so that your BC can't be satisfied if any contribution comes from $Y_0$. Hence your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation may be written as
$$
           r^2 v''(r)+rv'(r)-wr^2 v(r) = 0.
$$
You are interested in solutions for $w > 0$. It turns out that, if you find a solution $f(r)$ for $w=1$, then $v(r)=f(\sqrt{w}r)$ is a solution for the general $w > 0$. You can see this by substituting $v(r)=f(\sqrt{w}r)$ into your equation to obtain
$$
         r^2 wf''(\sqrt{w}r)+r\sqrt{w}f'(\sqrt{w}r)-wr^2 f(\sqrt{w}r) = 0 \\
         (\sqrt{w}r)^2 f''(\sqrt{w}r)+(\sqrt{w}r)f'(\sqrt{w}r)-(\sqrt{w}r)^2 f(\sqrt{w}r) = 0  \\
           s^2 f''(s)+sf'(s)-s^2f(s) = 0,\;\; s = \sqrt{w}r.
$$
This is a standard trick used to study the Bessel equation. The conclusion is that, if you know a solution $f(r)$ of your equation where $w=1$, then $y(r)=f(\sqrt{w}r)$ is a solution of your equation for a general $w > 0$.

The reduced equation is very close to the reduced Bessel equation of order $0$, which is
$$
           \rho^2 R''(\rho)+\rho R'(\rho)+\rho^2 R(\rho) = 0.
$$
The only obvious change between your equation and the reduced Bessel equation is the sign change for the $R$ term. The Bessel equation solutions extend into the complex plane, which is something you have to know in order to make sense of a substitution with $i=\sqrt{-1}$ in it. What you are really doing is solving the above equation for a function that is holomorphic in the slitted plane $\{ re^{i\theta} : -\pi < \theta < \pi, r > 0 \}$. Knowing that such a solution exists, then you can replace $\rho$ by $iz$, and the equation will still hold by the identity principle for holomorphic functions. However, I would say that the idea you can make a substitution $\rho = it$ for $t > 0$ is non-sensical without knowing a lot about the solutions of the equation, and about Complex Function Theory. Frankly, I think treating this as a "substitution" is sloppy Math, but that's my opinion. However, knowing that there are solutions that are holomorphic in the slitted plane, you can substitute $\rho = it$ where $t$ is real, and the resulting equation must continue to hold, i.e,
$$
                (it)^2 R''(it)+(it)R'(it) + (it)^2 R(it) = 0 \\
          t^2 \frac{d^2}{dt^2}R(it)+t\frac{d}{dt}R(it)-t^2R(it)=0
$$
That is, $S(t)=R(it)$ does satisfy
$$
                t^2 S''(t)+tS'(t)-t^2 S(t) = 0,
$$
which is your reduced equation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just don't understand the following point: how we pass from this equation $$z''(\xi)+\dfrac{1}{\xi}z'(\xi)- z(\xi)=, \  < \xi < \epsilon \sqrt{w}$$ to the equation $$y''(\zeta)+\dfrac{1}{\zeta}y'(\zeta)+y(\zeta)=0$$ where $\zeta= i\xi$?

Comment: @jiji : I explained that part in the last section of my solution. You really have to know that you have a holomorphic solution for the equation in a certain region. Then, just knowing that the equation is satisfied on the real line allows you to conclude that the equation is satisified on the imaginary axis, too, by the identity theorem for holomorphic functions. As I mentioned, it's not really proper to treat this is a "substitution." It ends up looking like a strange change-of-variables, but it's not really.

Comment: Don't you have $C_3(1+\frac{w}{4}\epsilon^2) = a$?

Comment: @TrialAndError: why *sloppy*? Since you know in advance that the solution is an entire function (the coefficients of $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{n!^2}$ decay pretty fast to zero!) there is no concern in substituting $z=ix$ or $\rho=it$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : At the point in the post where the substitution involving $i$ is made, there is nothing to justify being able to do what jiji records as having been done. So I offered justification for this step, which is one of the things asked about in the post. I would say that jiji is justified in wanting to see some justification for this.

Answer (score 1):

[Bessel's differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html) can be solved through Frobenius' power-series method and a solution for $n=0$ is given by the entire function 
$$ J_0(z)=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m\,x^{2m}}{4^m m!^2} $$
related with the Fourier series of $\arcsin(x)$. That is not an elementary function strictly speaking, but it is a really important function in dealing with some differential equations (especially some differential equations involving the Laplacian operator) and it deserves for sure to be studied, like the $\Gamma$ or Beta function.

That said, the shown solution just perform a change of variable in order to turn the given differential equation into a Bessel differential equation. The solutions depend on $J_0$ and there is nothing we may change about that.

Comment: Please, i don'tunderstand how and why we search to transform the equation given into an Bessel equation

Comment: @jiji: because we know *how to solve* a Bessel differential equation.

Comment: and how we transform the given equation into Bessel equation please. I don't understand this point, can you give me more details for this please.

Comment: @jiji: the *how* stands in front of your nose: through the substitution $\xi=r\sqrt{w}$.

Comment: The *asymptotic expansion* you mention is not really an asymptotic expansion, is just a Taylor series centered at $\zeta=0$.

Comment: but Bessel equation is $x^2 y'' +....$, and in my equation, the coefficient of y'' isn't $x^2$